# Hash Special character does not work in IFRAME

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net-3.5

The Request.QueryString comprises of the path 
eg. Temp\file#hashName.jpg

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string filePath = Request.QueryString["fileName"];
iframes.Attributes.Add("src", filePath);
}
```

it den goes to the Markup where i hav written javascript code

```
function ViewFile(filePath) {
    var width = 800;
    var height = 450;
    var left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2);
    var top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);
    window.open('ViewFile.aspx?fileName=' + filePath, 'CustomPopUp', 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ',toolbar=no,menubar=no,directories=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,location=no,top=' + top + ',left=' + left);
    return false;
}
```

but when I run, it shows me (in a new window)
"The resource cannot be found. "
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Temp/file 
as soon as it encounters a HASH it breaks the path... 
wen I used Server.URLEncode and HttpUtility.UrlEncode(); its converting / and # to respective values... bt showing message

HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.

Javascript Escape() EncodeURI() and EncodeURI component s also not working out.
What shall I do to escape # ?? does iframe accept # value in URL??? Kindly guide me through this.

Kind Regards,
Hardik

Comment: how about use replace function like, filePath = filePath.replace(/\#/ig, "");

Comment: Hi Max!! Thanks for replying..while saving time it s storing d filename with #...only while Viewing it in a new window its giving this problem...eventhough i will try it and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Where does ViewFile js function get the input filePath? Issue can be related to that. If the filePath has # in it then you can use `encodeURIComponent` such as

```
'ViewFile.aspx?fileName=' + encodeURIComponent(filePath)
```

However, there will be issue if `filePath` value to function is not correct because encoding issue elsewhere (e.g. IFrame source). Whenever you use # in URL/QueryString, it may cause an issue - so you should also try to escape it while assigning it to IFrame source.

Comment: Hi Vinay!! Thanks so much for replying!! you are right. there is an issue in the IFRAME source. The ViewFile js function is called from code behind after fetching the file path.While debugging time it shows the correct path i.e. Temp//file#hashname.jpg.Other files without # are being viewed correctly (even the file names like file.dotName.jpg are viewed correctly).Only the files with # are giving problem.
How do I escape # in Iframe source? The source of the Iframe is assigned in code behind
  
  string filePath = Request.QueryString["fileName"];
    iframes.Attributes.Add("src", filePath);

Comment: @user775829, try using `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode` to encode the url before adding as a source attribute to iframe.